# Pass const shared_ptr as argument

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have an issue understanding this code which is in a .m Objective-C file.

`void Execute (const std::shared_ptr<RProgram> program) {}`

What's the advantage of passing by const? I don't know if it has perf advantage or it shares the ownership of program?

I understand the following patterns

```
// this just takes the reference without changing the counter for perf. 
void Execute (const std::shared_ptr<RProgram>& program) {}
```

```
// this takes ownership 
void Execute (std::shared_ptr<RProgram> program) {}
```

Comment: If this function's signature is something that another user will be implementing, i.e. for a callback or subclass, then the `const` communicates that they should not modify that argument. I think there are many cases where passing a const reference is more appropriate than a const copy though. It could just be an oversight that they added const but didn't make it a reference.

Comment: Some people prefer to have `const` for there parameter (as `f(const int)`) to avoid to mutate them (as for local variables).

Comment: The reference ount is not stored in the `shared_ptr` object itself, it is stored in the control block that the `shared_ptr` holds a pointer to.  So, the refcount cold stil be updated even if the `shared_ptr` itself is `const`. which just means the `shared_ptr` can't be updated to take ownership of a different control block.

Comment: It's pass by value so a copy is made and this copy will share ownership. I can see this as helpful in preventing casual bugs, but I see no inherent performance advantage. [What the compiler does with it now that it knows the value is not to be changed...](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) that's up to the compiler.

Comment: "_in a .m Objective-C file._" - did you mean an `.mm` file?

Answer (score 2):

The  `const` in this signature

```
void Execute (const std::shared_ptr<RProgram> program) {}
```

means that inside the function `program` is `const`. Calling any non-const method would result in a compiler error. However, it has little to no meaning for the caller. It is not even considerd for the type of the function:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

void foo(const int) {}
void bar(int)  {}

void f(const std::shared_ptr<int>) {}
void g(std::shared_ptr<int>) {}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_same_v< decltype(foo),decltype(bar)> << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_same_v< decltype(f),decltype(g)> << "\n";
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/aWsaYh5Y6):

```
1
1
```